# Form field length validation in phpmailer

Tags: php, validation, phpmailer

I want to validate form fields by minimum and maximum length.

I'm already validating if if they're empty or if the email address is invalid. I want to add additional length requirements to each field (min. length and max. length). What would be best practice for this?

excerpt from my `process.php` file:

```
require_once('includes/phpmailer-config.php');
require_once('includes/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

// other stuff here

// Validate each form field
if (empty($name)) {
    $errors['name'] = MIA_NAME;    // Error message for missing name
}
if (empty($email)) {
    $errors['email'] = MIA_ADDR;   // Error message for missing email address
}
elseif (!(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))) {
    $errors['email'] = INV_ADDR;   // Error message for invalid email address
}
if (empty($message)) {
    $errors['message'] = MIA_MESG; // Error message for missing message
}
```

excerpt from my `phpmailer-config.php` file:

```
// other stuff here

define ('MIA_NAME', 'A Full Name is Required.');       // Error for missing name
define ('LG_NAME',  {5,50}');                          // Min. length: 5, Max. length: 50
define ('TS_NAME',  'Name is too Short.');             // Error for name too short 
define ('TL_NAME',  'Name is too Long.');              // Error for name too long

define ('MIA_ADDR', 'An Email Address is Required.');  // Error for missing email address
define ('LG_ADDR',  {8,50}');                          // Min. length: 8, Max. length: 50
define ('TS_ADDR',  'Email Address is too Short.');    // Error for email too short 
define ('TL_ADDR',  'Email Address is too Long.');     // Error for email too long
define ('INV_ADDR', 'We need a valid email address.'); // Error for invalid email address

define ('MIA_MESG', 'A Message is Required.');         // Error message for missing message
define ('LG_MESG',  {20,7500}');                       // Min. length: 20, Max. length: 7500
define ('TS_MESG',  'Message is too Short.');          // Error for message too short 
define ('TL_MESG',  'Message is too Long.');           // Error for message too long
```

---

**Edit:** Here's what I ended up using, thanks to Amal's answer:

Excerpt from `phpmailer-config.php`:

```
define ('MIA_NAME', 'A Full Name is Required.');       // Error for missing name
define ('MIN_NAME', 5);                                // Min. length for name 
define ('MAX_NAME', 50);                               // Max. length for name
define ('TS_NAME',  'Name is too Short.');             // Error for name too short 
define ('TL_NAME',  'Name is too Long.');              // Error for name too long

define ('MIA_ADDR', 'An Email Address is Required.');  // Error for missing email address
define ('MIN_ADDR', 8);                                // Min. length for email address
define ('MAX_ADDR', 50);                               // Max. length for email address
define ('TS_ADDR',  'Email Address is too Short.');    // Error for email too short 
define ('TL_ADDR',  'Email Address is too Long.');     // Error for email too long
define ('INV_ADDR', 'We need a valid email address.'); // Error for invalid email address

define ('MIA_MESG', 'A Message is Required.');         // Error message for missing message
define ('MIN_MESG', 20);                               // Min. length for message
define ('MAX_MESG', 7500);                             // Max. length for message
define ('TS_MESG',  'Message is too Short.');          // Error for message too short 
define ('TL_MESG',  'Message is too Long.');           // Error for message too long
```

Excerpt from `process.php`:

```
// Validate each form field
if (empty($name)) {
    $errors['name'] = MIA_NAME; }    // Missing name
elseif (strlen(trim($_POST['name'])) < MIN_NAME ) {
    $errors['name'] = TS_NAME; }     // Name too short
elseif (strlen(trim($_POST['name'])) > MAX_NAME ) {
    $errors['name'] = TL_NAME; }     // Name too long

if (empty($email)) {
    $errors['email'] = MIA_ADDR; }   // Missing email address
elseif (strlen(trim($_POST['email'])) < MIN_ADDR ) {
    $errors['email'] = TS_ADDR; }    // Email too short
elseif (strlen(trim($_POST['email'])) > MAX_ADDR ) {
    $errors['email'] = TL_ADDR; }    // Email too long
elseif (!(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))) {
    $errors['email'] = INV_ADDR; }   // Invalid email address

if (empty($message)) {
    $errors['message'] = MIA_MESG; } // Missing message
elseif (strlen(trim($_POST['message'])) < MIN_MESG ) {
    $errors['message'] = TS_MESG; }  // Message too short
elseif (strlen(trim($_POST['message'])) > MAX_MESG ) {
    $errors['message'] = TL_MESG; }  // Message too long
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML5, you can use the [pattern](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090825/forms.html#attr-input-pattern) attribute, like so:

```
<input pattern=".{5,25}" title="Input 5 to 25 characters">
```

Of course, this isn't secure. You'll need to validate the inputs server-side, too.

You can use [`strlen()`](http://php.net/strlen) to get the length of the input value, and then use `if` conditional statements to check if they're within the pre-defined length range.

```
$length = strlen(trim($_POST['name']));
if ( $length >= 5 && $length <= 25) {
    # code...
}
```

Integrating it into your current code, it'd be something like:

```
if (empty($name)) {
    $errors['name'] = MIA_NAME;    // Error message for missing name
}

if (strlen(trim($_POST['name'])) >= 5) {
    # code ...
} elseif (strlen(trim($_POST['name'])) <= 25) {
    # code ...
}

if (empty($email)) {
    $errors['email'] = MIA_ADDR;   // Error message for missing email address
} elseif (!(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))) {
    $errors['email'] = INV_ADDR;   // Error message for invalid email address
}

if (empty($message)) {
    $errors['message'] = MIA_MESG; // Error message for missing message
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Where would I integrate this in my own validation logic? I'm specifically referring to the order of `if` and `elseif` statements. I'd also like different messages for a too short string and a too long string. To make this modular, I'd want to specify the lengths in my `config.php` file.

Comment: @Daze: I've updated the answer. However, I'm not actually sure how to read the maximum and minimum allowed lengths from your config file (`{20,7500}`), so I'll just leave it at that. I think it'd be better to define multiple constants for minimum and maximum length and use that the `if-elseif` block instead.

Comment: Thanks again, Amal. It would indeed be simpler to use separate constants for min and max. I've integrated additional `if` and `elseif` statements in my form thanks to your updated answer. For reference, I've updated my question with the code I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

```
$name= clean_input($_POST['name']); //A custom function to make sure it's a clean string
if(strlen($name) > 100)
{
  //Something weird
}
else
{
  //We're good
}
```